# Is there an over-arcing term for this style of movie?

Tags: terminology, genre

I am wondering if there is a label or term for the particular style of movie that provides just enough plot upon which to hang some specialty focused features.

The three top examples would be:

- **Porn**: Thin plot setting up detailed sex scenes.
- **Musicals**: Thin-to-medium plot to set up elaborate song and dance numbers.
- **Kung Fu/Martial Arts**: Basic plot to lead into extended combat ballets.

Comment: If something gets these all three, and combine them to have a good outcome, then it have all. one of the best movies to get high box office ratings :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term you may be looking for is ["Excuse Plot"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExcusePlot). TV Tropes (obligatory warning: it's highly addictive!) describes the concept thusly:

> An Excuse Plot is, in the simplest terms, a plot that is clearly there merely as a justification for the gameplay, or other form of flashy, show-offy-ness, to happen. [...] An Excuse Plot is not necessarily a poorly written, minimalistic, or stupid storyline, only one that has been written to obviously showcase something else.

The site mostly relates it to video games - "the princess has been kidnapped, go save her" - but I'd argue it works equally well for all the genres you've listed. There's even a specific sub-trope related to porn plots: [Pizza Boy's Special Delivery](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PizzaBoySpecialDelivery).